# Does putting questions on hold affect their answers?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to determine why [this answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/a/423746/60384) was deleted. I understand that the question itself does not sound very professional, which is why it was put on hold.

Does the question being put on hold delete its answers, either automatically or manually due to policy? Or was something in my answer sufficiently out of line to warrant deletion?

*P.S.: This is not about the reputation loss - it's about understanding the policy and conventions in SF better.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the question was closed here it was "sent back" to the original site (SO).
So everything on the rejecting site (SF) gets "cleaned up".

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I was unaware of that little detail...

Comment: ...and I just realised that mine was one of the original close votes on SO. Life is a circle...